# Parse Cloud set and get functions

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a simple getter and setter functions for a String value using Parse Cloud but for some reason it doesn't work. I searched the Parse documentation and forums but couldn't find the reason. Please advise me.

```
function setPassword(newPass){
    console.log('setPassword() started with input ' +newPass);
    var PasswordItem = Parse.Object.extend("PasswordItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(PasswordItem);
    if (query.length > 0) {
        if (query[0].password != newPass) {
            console.log('setPassword() found existing password. replacing it with ' +newPass);
            query[0].password = newPass;
        }else{
            console.log('setPassword() found existing password. existing password is the same as the new one');
        }
    }else{
        console.log('setPassword() no existing password. creating new password: ' +newPass);
        var passwordItem = new PasswordItem();
        passwordItem.set("password", newPass);
        passwordItem.save(null, {
            success: function (results) {
                console.log("Save ok");
                response.success(results);
            },
            error: function (results, error) {
                console.log("Save error");
                response.error(error);
            }});
    }
}

function getPassword(){
    console.log('getPassword() started');
    var password = new String();
    var PasswordItem = Parse.Object.extend("PasswordItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(PasswordItem);
    if (query.length > 0) {
        password = query[0].password;
    }else{
        password = "";
    }
    console.log('getPassword() returns ' +password);
    return password;
}
```

P.S please ignore security issues related to passwords, this is just an example.

Comment: Where is this code failing? I can see at least one issue in that you don't save the password after you've replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of attempts, I got this code working for me. Seems my main problem in understanding was that the Parse function save() is asynchronous and therefor I cannot expect to have the result available without using Futures.
I'm new to JavaScript so will appreciate any comment.

```
function getPassword(req, res){
    console.log('getPassword() started');
    var query = new Parse.Query(PasswordItem);
    query.descending('createdAt');
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            console.log('getPassword() successfully found ' +results.length +' passwords');
            if (results.length > 0){
                password = results[0].get("password");
                console.log('getPassword() got password ' +password);
            }else{
                password = "";
                console.log('getPassword() got empty password');
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('getPassword() error searching for passwords ' +error.message);
            password = null;
        }
    }).then(function() {
            renderAll(req, res);
    });
    console.log('getPassword() ended');
}

function setPassword(req, res){
    console.log('setPassword() started with input ' +newPass);
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var newPass = req.body.password;
    var query = new Parse.Query(PasswordItem);
    if (query.length > 0) {
        if (query[0].password != newPass) {
            console.log('setPassword() found existing password. replacing it with ' +newPass);
            query[0].password = newPass;
        }else{
            console.log('setPassword() found existing password. existing password is the same as the new one');
        }
    }else{
        console.log('setPassword() no existing password. creating new password: ' +newPass);
        var passwordItem = new PasswordItem();
        passwordItem.set("password", newPass);
        passwordItem.save(null, {
            success: function(results) {
                console.log("Save ok");
            },
            error: function(results, error) {
                console.log("Save error");
            }
        }).then(function(input) { 
                getPassword(req, res);
            });
    }
}

function clearPasswords(req, res){
    console.log('clearPasswords() started');
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(PasswordItem);
    query.descending('createdAt');
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            console.log('clearPasswords() successfully found ' +results.length +' passwords');
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                results[i].destroy();
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('clearPasswords() error searching for passwords ' +error.message);
        }
    }).then(function() {
            setPassword(req, res);
    });
    console.log('clearPasswords() ended');
}
```